# Google Calendar API HttpError 404 for calendar ID

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I was using a modified version of the Google Calendar API Python Quickstart code that worked fine for me for a while.  I recently just got a new computer and have been transferring files to it.  Now when I run the script, I get a HTTPError 404. Code is below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

import datetime

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/calendar-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.

    Creates a Google Calendar API service object and outputs a list of the next
    10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC 
time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')

"""Below, I switched out 'primary' with the calendarId of the calendar I 
actually wanted"""

    eventsResult = service.events().list(
        calendarId='redacted@group.calendar.google.com', timeMin=now, 
maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have noticed that when I replace the 'calendarId' with 'primary' instead of the calendar Id that I want, the code works fine.  I can't figure out why I get the error message for this when this exact same code worked fine on my previous machine.  Here's the full error message below (redacted):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\redacted.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\redacted.py", line 73, in main
    orderBy='startTime').execute()
  File "C:\redacted\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
   packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\redacted\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 844, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
  googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting 
    https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/redacted=json returned 
    "Not Found">
```

Can anyone help explain what I'm missing?

Comment: What is the value of the calendarId that you are replacing? It should be the email address of the user using your app. Also if you are accessing another calendarID other than their own, it should be shared to the user accessing it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it.  So simple and makes me feel so dumb.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the email address of the user using your app. Also if you are accessing another calendarID other than their own, it should be shared to the user accessing it.

> **`calendarId`**
>
> - Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the [**`calendarList.list`**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged in user, use the "`primary`" keyword.

See the imag below:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: "should be the email address of the user using your app [...] if you are accessing another calendarID other than their own, it should be shared to the user accessing it" - what if it's a secondary calendar that the user has, i.e. not their primary calendar (which would be accessed either by passing their email or 'primary')? I'm trying to insert a new secondary calendar using .insert() but am getting the error above.